# Opening racket source files in DrRacket by default?

Tags: gedit, default-programs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When i open a rkt file, it opens in gedit by default. 
I tried changing it in properties (the default open with) but it opens other plain text documents (like txt file) in drRacket as well.
 How can i customize it to selecrivwly open racket files in drRacket? 
Also if i rename file to scm it opens in DrRacket on its own!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the solution.
.rkt isnt a default mimetype in ubuntu, though .scm.
All i needed was to set up a new mimetype.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1olY5Qzmbk8) video tutorial helped me. 
(Still have to figure out if there's a way it shows Drracket icon for .rkt files)

Cheers :D.